# American English single-plural usage

Tags: differences

"people" and "money" previously were used to denote plural. Now we have "peoples" and "moneys". What is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you clarify the question for me a little? It's not clear if you're looking for an etymological explanation or a definition. If the latter, can you include the definitions you see in a dictionary when you look up these words? Also, providing the context you saw these words in would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about _moneys_, but _peoples_ is a pretty normal and old plural for _people_ when you mean (for instance) ethnic groups.

Answer (score 1):

The word "peoples" semantically differs from "people".

From OALD:

> people [people peoples peopled peopling] noun, verb
>
> 1. plural persons; men, women and children
>
>    - At least ten people were killed in the crash.
>    - There were a lot of people at the party.
>    - Many young people are out of work.
> 2. plural persons in general or everyone
>
>    - He doesn't care what people think of him.
>    - She tends to annoy people.  Use everyone or everybody instead of ‘all people’.
> 3. countable all the persons who live in a particular place or belong to a particular country, race, etc
>
>    - the French *people*
>    - the native *peoples* of Siberia

As you can see above, "**people**" in the context of **3.** means an **ethnic group** or a **group of inhabitants** occupying a specific region. The word may thus be in the form of "**peoples**" if you refer to multiple groups, the same way you could use "**groups**".

The two forms (peoples and people) are *not* interchangeable, meaning that it is *incorrect* to use "peoples" in the context of 1. or 2. or the other way around (with the exception of "a people", of course, which means a single ethnic group).

---

The same applies to "monies".

From OALD:

> money [money moneys monies] noun
>
> 1. uncountable what you earn by working or selling things, and use to buy things
>
>    - to borrow/save/spend/earn money
>    - How much money is there in my account?
>    - The money is much better in my new job.
>    - If the item is not satisfactory, you will get your money back.
>    - We'll need to raise more money (= collect or borrow it) next year.
>    - Can you lend me some money until tomorrow?
>    - Be careful with that — it cost a lot of money.
> 2. uncountable coins or paper notes
>
>    - I counted the money carefully.
>    - Where can I change my money into dollars?
> 3. uncountable a person's wealth including their property
>
>    - He lost all his money.
>    - The family made their money in the 18th century.
> 4. moneys or *monies* plural (law or old use) **sums of money**
>
>    - a statement of all monies paid into your account

I have often seen "**monies**" used, but *exclusively* in legal text such as contracts, statutes and court documents. It is a term of art used in legal contexts only and is interchangeable with "**funds**".